# Droid X issue, Buttons not appearing. (Android)

Tags: android

When running on droid X my app does not show buttons that are written in xml. I only found this after releasing my app and users reported it. This XML code does not appear on Droid X. Any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <LinearLayout
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:text="NAME"
        android:textColor="#FF0000" 
        android:textSize="10pt"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_width="120dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  <TextView
        android:text=" DAY: "
        android:textColor="#FF0000" 
        android:textSize="7pt"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/days"
        android:text="DAY"
        android:textColor="#FF0000" 
        android:textSize="7pt"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <TextView
        android:text=" "
        android:textColor="#33CC33" 
        android:textSize="7pt"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="125dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 <TextView

        android:text="CASH: $"
        android:textColor="#33CC33" 
        android:textSize="7pt"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cash"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="#33CC33" 
        android:textSize="7pt"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 </LinearLayout>       
        <View android:layout_height="2dip" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FF0000" />
    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/note1"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FF0000" 
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <View android:layout_height="1dip" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FF0000" />
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/note2"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FF0000" 
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <View android:layout_height="3dip" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FF0000" />


    </LinearLayout>
   <include android:id="@+id/bank"
         layout="@layout/bank"
         android:layout_height="330dip"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         />
         <include android:id="@+id/buysell"
         layout="@layout/buysell"
         android:layout_height="330dip"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         />
           <include android:id="@+id/travel"
         layout="@layout/travel"
         android:layout_height="330dip"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         />
          <include android:id="@+id/info"
         layout="@layout/info"
         android:layout_height="330dip"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         />


    <View android:layout_height="2dip" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FF0000" />     
      <LinearLayout
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">    
  <Button 
        android:id="@+id/buy_btn"
        android:text="BUY/SELL"
        android:textColor="#FF0000" 
        android:textSize="7pt"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<Button 
        android:id="@+id/bank_btn"
        android:text="BANK"
        android:textColor="#FF0000" 
        android:textSize="7pt"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  <Button 
        android:id="@+id/move_btn"
        android:text="RELOCATE"
        android:textColor="#FF0000" 
        android:textSize="7pt"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  <Button 
        android:id="@+id/info_btn"
        android:text="INFO"
        android:textColor="#FF0000" 
        android:textSize="7pt"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>



</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**could a mod please edit this. i cant get the xml file to display correctly**

Comment: We need more information, maybe showing us some code would help us answer your question.

Comment: @ your added code: We still need more information, give us some more code than that to evaluate.

Comment: What else specifically? I'm not getting any errors. None of the buttons in my layouts are appearing

Comment: Why not show us the layout that is holding those buttons? Are you unable to just post the whole xml file?

Comment: Also where you're using the button and how.

Comment: I edited the post to have the xml show up correctly. Is this still a proble? Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your xml view is still messed up, however... at the beginning of you file are you adding this into the beginning of your xml layout?
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

I do not see it there in the unmodified version of your xml. Try adding that into your linearlayout tag at the top of your xml and maybe that will solve your problem.

Example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
</LinearLayout>
```